# How can I define a string format for a double that displays the value as if it was divided?

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

Suppose I have a `double = 99.00;`. How can  I define a string `format` that will output me a string like `"0.099"` when using `double.ToString(format);`. As you can see I want to format my double as if it was divided by `1000`.

I know I could do something like:

```
double number = 99.00;
string formattedNumber = (number / 1000).ToString("0.000");
Console.WriteLine(formattedNumber); // Output: "0.099"
```

However, is there a way to directly define a format without any additional calculation?

Comment: No there isn't and that output is not correct.

Comment: *Me confidently posting, without testing once*, Thanks!

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"{number/1000}")` is the closest thing i could think of.

Comment: don't use int (`1000`) for division always use a floating point type eg. double `1000.0` or `1000d`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [scaling formatter (`,`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SpecifierTh) directly to the left of the decimal point to scale down the number by 1,000:

```
double number = 99.00;
string formattedNumber = number.ToString("0,.000");
Console.WriteLine(formattedNumber); // Output: "0.099"
```

You can use multiple commas to scale by powers of 1,000 (e.g. `,,` will divide by 1,000,000)

The formatter is commonly used to show data in a different order of magnitude (e.g. displaying data in Thousands or Millions to save space)

Although unless you could *only* specify a formatting string without changing the data (e.g. in a report or form) I would just scale the number before displaying and use standard formatting strings. It may not be obvious that the formatting string above is scaling the number unless you use it often.

Comment: but JonSkeet said `No, there isn't.` so you must be lying. ;)

Comment: here the documentation to that outrages lie: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-2

Comment: Gosh, I've read that documentation several times but never seen the aspect of scaling. Comment deleted :)